# MySQL select from 2 tables (One with messages / Second that stores hidden messages)

Tags: php, mysql

Good Morning. I have been struggling with MySQL problem that I can't solve.

Problem: I don't understand how to `SELECT` needed data. (SubQuery/INNER JOIN/more?)

I got two tables: `user_pm` and `user_pm_hide`

In `user_pm` I store messages:

[image: user_pm_image]

In `user_pm_hide` I store hidden ("Deleted Messages") from that user, who has "Deleted" it.

[image: user_pm_hide_image]

For example I receive `Inbox Count` **This works**

```
$stmt = $this->conn->prepare("SELECT count(*) FROM user_pm WHERE sentto=('$username')");
$stmt->execute();
$inboxall = $stmt->fetchColumn();

$stmt = $this->conn->prepare("SELECT count(*) FROM user_pm_hide WHERE user_id=('$username')");
$stmt->execute();
$inboxhidden = $stmt->fetchColumn();

$inboxtotal = $inboxall - $inboxhidden;
```

But I can't figure out, how to show messages, that's not hidden. I'm trying to achieve it like this:

```
SELECT user_pm.*, (SELECT * FROM user_pm_hide WHERE user_id != $username) FROM user_pm user_pm WHERE sentto=('$username')
```

Error that I get now :

> SQLSTATE[21000]: Cardinality violation: 1241 Operand should contain 1 column(s)

Comment: Get rid of all this PHP stuff and see https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query

Comment: @Strawberry Thanks, for advice. Will edit now.

Comment: You are calling fetchColumn instead of getting the row from the results. Also, instead of two tables, why not just have a flag column in the 1st table for deleted messages?

Comment: @SloanThrasher I'm begginer in programming and don't really understand how to do it.

Comment: You're welcome. Let us know once you've edited.

Answer (score 0):

You are missing the singe quotes in the inner `SELECT` part. Try

```
SELECT 
  user_pm.*, 
  (SELECT * FROM user_pm_hide WHERE user_id != '$username') 
FROM 
  user_pm 
WHERE 
  sentto=('$username')
```